# rails 6 set a CSP policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, sprite, content-security-policy, webpacker

i am trying to setup a CSP policy (collected from: [Evil Martian Blog](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/rails-5-2-active-storage-and-beyond)):

```
 Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
   policy.font_src    :self, :https, :data
   policy.img_src     :self, :https, :data
   policy.object_src  :none
   policy.style_src   :self, :https, :unsafe_inline
   # If you are using webpack-dev-server then specify webpack-dev-server host
   if Rails.env.development?
     policy.script_src :self, :http, :unsafe_inline
     ## policy.script_src :self, :http, :unsafe_eval
     policy.default_src :self, :http, :unsafe_eval
     policy.connect_src :self, :http, 'http://localhost:3035', 'ws://localhost:3035', 'http://localhost:3000', 'ws://localhost:3000'
   else
     policy.script_src :self, :https, :unsafe_inline
     policy.default_src :self, :https
   # Specify URI for violation reports
     # policy.report_uri "/csp-violation-report-endpoint"
   end
 end
```

EDIT = >  I ended up using the secure_headers gem and followed advise contained in https://bauland42.com/ruby-on-rails-content-security-policy-csp/

There are two issues that seems to prevent the implementation in development mode :

1/ it seems to prevent toaster notification (installed from webpacker)

How can I allow toaster notifications ?

Solved by adding :unsafe_inline. to the dev environment also

2/ an inline script in application.html.erb

this is solved as well but I will be happy to move the script below if I can reference injectSvgSprite('<%= asset_url("icons/icons.svg") %>'). to work from the javascript folder.

How can I allow the inline script ?  I am happy to move this to javascript folder but could not link the sprite folder.

the head contains : `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>`. and `<%= csp_meta_tag %>`

then comes:

```
<body>

  <%= custom_bootstrap_flash %>

  <%= yield %>

  <script>
    // ------------------------------------------------------- //
    //   Inject SVG Sprite -
    //   see more here
    //   https://css-tricks.com/ajaxing-svg-sprite/
    // ------------------------------------------------------ //

    function injectSvgSprite(path) {

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("GET", path, true);
        ajax.send();
        ajax.onload = function(e) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = 'd-none';
        div.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        }
    }

    injectSvgSprite('<%= asset_url("icons/icons.svg") %>')

  </script>
<!-- Swiper Carousel -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT =>  I have setup svg inline using the svgeez gem [enter link description here](https://github.com/jgarber623/svgeez)

3/ as subsidiary here : Sipper needs the above CDN to work

I have yarn installed swiper, and required it in application.js, include it in the pack_tag but I still need to reference the can for the javascript (css worked without it). What have I missed ?